# Why can't I load appleid.apple.com in webbrowser control in vb.net?

Tags: webbrowser-control

If you guys try to WebBrowser1.Navigate("appleid.apple.com") it doesn't load. Why not?

WebBrowser1.Navigate("appleid.apple.com")

Is it because the site is https? Or maybe it uses javascript? Help!

Answer (score 0):

The URL is incomplete.
"http(s)://appleid.apple.com"